# Mac boot from Ubuntu installed on a USB drive

Tags: boot, usb, mac, refit

I have a USB drive with Ubuntu installed on it (on a Live USB, it actually has Ubuntu installed on it), and it works seamlessly when I try to boot my PC from it.

When I try to boot my mac (Mac Book Pro 15" 6,2) off of it, it wouldn't recognize it. I tried installing rEFIt and rEFInd on my Mac but neither seemed to help. How can I make it work? Is there any other boot menu intended for USBs? (rEFIt says on it's website it doesn't support USBs that great) Is there any way to manually program it? It is really important for me.

The USB drive is a San Disk Cruzer Pop 8 GB.

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing the rEFInd driver for whatever Linux filesystem you used on the USB flash drive. (rEFInd comes with ext2/3fs, ext4fs, and ReiserFS drivers.) That *might* enable rEFInd to read and boot the kernel, but you'll also need to either manually enter kernel options (by pressing F2 or Insert twice after you highlight the Linux option) or create a `/boot/refind_linux.conf` file to hold those options.

If installing the appropriate filesystem driver doesn't help, then chances are the EFI isn't activating the USB flash drive. It might be possible to write a simple EFI driver to do this, but that would take a fair amount of expertise to do.